# How to hide parameters in url?

Tags: url, parameters, hide

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I want to know how to hide parameters in an url.
Example: `wwww.test.ro/index?id=5&name=Jack&user=17` I want to be like this : `wwww.test.ro/index`. Is there a possibility to do that ?

Comment: If the parameters aren't in the URL, where will the script get them from?

Comment: @Barmar - the parameters are in the url, but the user can't see them. I heard rumors that it is possible to do that from htaccess, but Im not sure

Comment: You can use rewrite rules in `.htaccess`.

Comment: But if you do that, you would have to hard-code the parameters.

Comment: ok, but how can i do that? can you write me an example? thx

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very knowledgeable about .htaccess. There are many SO and ServerFault questions that explain how to use rewrite rules.

Comment: @barmar - what do you mean by "hard-code the parameters" ?